# How to build a Container without /proc?

Tags: linux, security, docker, kubernetes, proc

I would like to run my process in a container without /proc/ filesystem. How can it be achieved?

My intention is, that an attacker can not use a security flaw in a containerized application to read e.g. /proc/self/cmdline

How to create a (docker) image, that doesn't contain a /proc/? I don't see any documented docker umount commands.
Or do I need to tell kubernetes from mounting /proc/ into the container?

Comment: The Docker container sees a heavily filtered version of `/proc`  - see [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225374/is-accessing-proc-inside-docker-container-a-security-breach).